# Call Action<T> multiple times with collection as input

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I have a pretty standard benchmarking method, which counts the number of times a method can run in, say, 60 seconds:

```
    public static int BenchmarkTasks(Action<int> func, List<int> ids, int seconds)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        var executionCount = 0;

        watch.Start();

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 > seconds)
                return executionCount;

            func(id);
            executionCount++;
        }

        watch.Stop();

        return executionCount;
    }
```

However, I'm trying to figure out how to call this method correctly - for instance:

```
var ids = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
BenchmarkHelper.BenchmarkTasks(delegate { MethodToBenchmark(-1); }, ids, 60);
```

simply runs the method `MethodToBenchmark` with `-1` as the input value (understandably), it doesn't iterate through my collection of Ids.

Can anyone please let me know where I'm going wrong? Sure it's just me misunderstanding how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: `BenchmarkHelper.BenchmarkTasks(MethodToBenchmark, ids, 60);` This should be enough if `MethodToBenchmark` returns void and take one int parameter.

Comment: Isn't it a little bit akward to name something of type `Action` func? ;-)

Comment: I've just noticed that this method doesn't quite do what you describe it as doing. It won't count the number of times a method can run in 60 seconds as it will stop after `ids` has been exhausted. So in your example the maximum it can return is 3. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @petelids The 'real' collection would never normally be exhausted in 60 seconds; however I think it might be safer to start at the beginning again, if the collection ever runs out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `delegate` - you just need to pass the method directly. Otherwise you are passing an `Action` that calls `MethodToBenchmark(-1)` each time.

This is how you should call it:

```
var ids = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
BenchmarkHelper.BenchmarkTasks(MethodToBenchmark, ids, 60);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call it by using anonymous methods like this:

```
BenchmarkHelper.BenchmarkTasks((i) => MethodToBenchmark(i), ids, 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda expression to pass parameter:

```
BenchmarkHelper.BenchmarkTasks(id => MethodToBenchmark(id), ids, 60);
```